# Google Cloud Functions - Python deployment failing - Deployment failure: Function failed on loading user code

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to re-deploy a previously working Python cloud function using the inline editor.  With no changes to the source or requirements.txt, the deployment is failing with the following error message:

```
Deployment failure:
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Error: cannot communicate with function.
```

The function logs provide the following detail:

```
{
 insertId: "-xueafgcygm"  
 logName: "projects/xxx/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"  
 operation: {
  id: "operations/YXBvdGV4MzYwL3VzLWNlbnRyYWwxL2RvTG9hZEFwb3RleDM2MFByb2R1Y3QvSHhiWWlvVHVmdkE"   
  last: true   
  producer: "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com"   
 }
 protoPayload: {
  @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"   
  authenticationInfo: {
   principalEmail: "xxx@gmail.com"    
  }
  methodName: "google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction"   
  requestMetadata: {
   destinationAttributes: {
   }
   requestAttributes: {
   }
  }
  resourceName: "projects/xxx/locations/us-central1/functions/doLoadProduct"   
  serviceName: "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com"   
  status: {
   code: 3    
   message: "INVALID_ARGUMENT"    
  }
 }
 receiveTimestamp: "2019-11-04T16:17:00.108301794Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   function_name: "doLoadProduct"    
   project_id: "xxx"    
   region: "us-central1"    
  }
  type: "cloud_function"   
 }
 severity: "ERROR"  
 timestamp: "2019-11-04T16:16:59.612Z"  
}
```

This started happening last Friday, and continues today.  I have also tried local deployment using gcloud functions deploy where I receive the similar error message:

`ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Error: cannot communicate with function.`

I would appreciate some direction on next steps to resolve this.

--- Update ---

With Dustin's suggestions to provide the source and requirements file, I worked to see if I could re-create the issue with the minimal amount of code as possible.

main.py

```
import base64
import mysql.connector as db
from google.cloud import storage

def hello_pubsub(event, context):
    pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
    print(pubsub_message)
```

requirements.txt

```
google-cloud-storage==1.21.0
mysql-connector-python==8.0.18
```

It turns out that the versions of google-cloud-storage are incompatible.  Change to mysql-connector-phthon<8.0.18 and the function deploys normally.

So the issue is resolved.

Comment: Can you include your function and `requirements.txt`?

Comment: Have there been any changes to the Cloud Functions service accounts? This might be a transient error. After a few hours try again.

Answer (score 0):

As Dustin mentioned, it would be helpful if you share your **function**'s code and the content of **requirements.txt** file.

Based on the error (without having more specific information), it seems to me that the issue is coming from your Cloud Functions configuration. If it is the case, it could help to **reset the configuration** of your Cloud Functions, however, it would also require to **delete** your functions. You can achieve it by doing the following:

- Go to **Google Cloud Console** -> **APIs & Services** - > **Cloud Functions API** -> **Disable API**
- **Disable** Google Cloud Functions API.
- **Enable** the API again.
- Try to **deploy** the function.

Please let me know if it helps or provide more details, so that I could take a deeper look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by using mysql-connector-python<8.0.18

Thanks for help and suggestions.